# Bad image quality when save bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I'm working with bitmap and have some problems with save bitmap into file system as jpg file. i need to help: My app works as below:

1.Load JPG image file(1) from file system to bitmap1.

2.Draw bitmap1 to bitmap2.

3.Save bitmap2 as JPG image file(2).

i want to save JPG file(2) with 32 bit depth same as file(1).

```
    public OrderProcessor(OrderProcessorParams imageProcessorParams)
    {
        if (imageProcessorParams == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(imageProcessorParams));
        }

        this.imageProcessorParams = imageProcessorParams;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Start()
    {
        Bitmap destinationImage = null;
        var exportFolderPath = GetExportFolderPath();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(exportFolderPath);

        using (var sourceImage = Image.FromFile(imageProcessorParams.SourceImagePath))
        {
            destinationImage = GetDestinationImage();

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destinationImage))
            {
                SetGraphicSettings(graphics);

                graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage,
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(imageProcessorParams.Width.ToInch() * imageProcessorParams.Dpi),
                        (int)(imageProcessorParams.Height.ToInch() * imageProcessorParams.Dpi)));

                destinationImage.Save(Path.Combine(exportFolderPath, GetDestinationImageName()), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }
        }

        destinationImage.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Fields

    private readonly OrderProcessorParams imageProcessorParams;

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private Bitmap GetDestinationImage()
    {
        int width = (int)(imageProcessorParams.Width.ToInch() * imageProcessorParams.Dpi);
        int height = (int)((imageProcessorParams.Height.ToInch() + imageProcessorParams.FooterSize.ToInch()) * imageProcessorParams.Dpi);

        var destinationImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb);

        destinationImage.SetResolution(imageProcessorParams.Dpi, imageProcessorParams.Dpi);

        return destinationImage;
    }

    private string GetExportFolderPath()
    {
        var sourceImageFolderPath = new DirectoryInfo(imageProcessorParams.SourceImagePath).Parent.FullName;
        var destinationFolderName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        return Path.Combine(sourceImageFolderPath, destinationFolderName);
    }

    private string GetDestinationImageName()
    {
        return
            $"{Path.GetFileName(imageProcessorParams.SourceImagePath)} {imageProcessorParams.Width}X{imageProcessorParams.Height}.{ImageFormat.Jpeg}";
    }


    #endregion

    #region Static Members

    private static void SetGraphicSettings(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Just the nature of the beast.  JPEG is a lossy compressed format, resizing it and recompressing again never makes it better.

Comment: Are you erlarging the image? That will not add any information..

Comment: @HansPassant : i want to save JPG file(2) with 32 bit depth same as file(1).

Comment: @TaW: i draw source image to destination image.

Comment: Makes no sense, the JPEG codec only supports 24bpp.  If you treat it like 32bpp in code we cannot see then, yes, that's going to look pretty wonky.

Comment: @HansPassant: source image format is jpg and support 32bpp. Can i save bitmap to file with jpg format and 32bpp like same as source image??

Comment: Yes, if you do it right you will not loose a lot of information but we can't help beyond what we told you.